# Can infinitive be moved in a "It is ... that" sentence?

Tags: infinitives

For example,

He planned *to go to Rome to study Italian*.

→ It was *to go to Rome to study Italian* that he planned.

Comment: Compare: 1. "He planned *the robbery* and 2. "It is *the robbery* that he planned." Both are possible but the meanings may differ depending on the context. ++ "to go to Rome to study Italian" is a substantive.

Comment: No, but you could say "It was (in order to) to study Italian that he planned to go to Rome", or the pseudo-cleft: "What he planned was to go to Rome to study Italian".

Comment: Too Yoda-esque is your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *to*-infinitival *to go to Rome* may not be separated from the verb that licenses it *planned* and foregrounded in the it-cleft construction. This is possible with objects - noun phrases, but not with *to*-infinitival complements.

*It was her death that I desired.*

*
*It was to kill her that I desired.*

*to*-infinitivals may be foregrounded if they are adjuncts of purpose:

*It was to study Italian that he planned to go to Rome.*

Comment: Yeah, the _It_-cleft is very clumsy that way with infinitives; a _Wh_-cleft is much more efficatious: _What he planned was to go to Rome to study Italian_.

Comment: I agree your last example is "valid", but I'd much prefer the somewhat easier to parse version *It was **in order** to study Italian that he planned to go to Rome* if I ***had*** to use this rather awkward construction.

Comment: This may be true, but even scholarly-sounding answers on ELU are considered less than optimal if they don't have attributed and linked supporting references. They may otherwise be considered (and may actually be) opinion, or single-school. _And I'd like to see usage-panel data on the acceptability of 'It was to study Italian that he planned to go to Rome.'_